# Order ASC e DESC de acordo com custom_field

Tags: php, wordpress

Tenho uma sessão do site (WordPress) onde eu adiciono parceiros de acordo com a categoria usando Custom Post Type. É um site de salão de festas. Cada categoria do custom post type representa um ramo. Ex das categorias: Buffet, Fotógrafos, Etc.

Até aí tudo bem. Está funcionando Ok.

Tem um campo criado como custom field chamado "wpcf-prioridade-parceiro" e eu quero que funcione assim: Se for igual a 0 ordena os parceiros em ordem alfabética normal. Se o valor for diferente de zero (de 1 a 9) ele tem que ordenar estes acima dos parceiros listados com 0 e por ordem de prioridade decrescente. 9 acima do 8, 8 acima do 7 e aí por diante.

A intenção é de quando um parceiro pagar pra ficar em evidencia ele vai pro topo da lista de acordo com a prioridade (de 1 a 9) e os que ficarem setados como 0 ficam em ordem alfabética abaixo dos que estão prioritários.

Ps.: Sou designer, me aventuro no PHP de orelhada. Mas tem hora que tenho que pedir um HELP.

O que eu fiz está listando os prioritários de forma correta no topo da lista em ordem decrescente do 9 a 1, mas os que estão com prioridade 0 estão listados em ordem alfabética decrescente também (De Z a A), mas quero que estes sejam listados alfabeticamente de A a Z e abaixo dos prioritários.

Como fazer um 'order' => 'ASC' ordenando pelo título apenas para os que estão com o campo "wpcf-prioridade-parceiro" listados como 0?

Eis o que eu fiz:

```
<?php

$args=array(
'post_type' => 'parceiros',
'posts_per_page' => 150,
'meta_key' => 'wpcf-prioridade-parceiro',
'orderby' => 'wpcf-prioridade-parceiro',
'order' => 'ASC');

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Penso que o melhor será realizares duas consultas, uma com as prioridades ordenadas de 9 a 1, e outra com as prioridades 0 ordenadas alfabeticamente.

Com os resultados podes fazer uso do plugin [WordPress plugin - Combine Queries](https://github.com/birgire/wp-combine-queries) para juntar os resultados e continuar normalmente a partir dai:

## Consulta apenas prioridades 1 a 9

```
/* Consulta apenas prioridades 1 a 9
 */
$args1 = array(
    'post_type'      => 'parceiros',
    'posts_per_page' => 150,
    'meta_key'       => 'wpcf-prioridade-parceiro',
    'meta_type'      => 'NUMERIC',
    'orderby'        => 'wpcf-prioridade-parceiro',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'wpcf-prioridade-parceiro',
            'value'   => array( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
```

## Consulta apenas prioridade 0 ordenado

```
/* Consulta apenas prioridade 0 ordenado
 */
$args2 = array(
    'post_type'      => 'parceiros',
    'posts_per_page' => 150,
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'wpcf-prioridade-parceiro',
            'value'   => '0',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);
```

### Combinar as consultas

```
/* combinar as consultas
 */
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 150,
    'paged'          => ( $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? $paged : 1 ,
    'args'           => array( $args1, $args2 ),
);
```

### Obter resultados

```
if( class_exists( 'WP_Combine_Queries' ) ):
    $q = new WP_Combine_Queries( $args );
    if( $q->have_posts() ):
        ?><ul><?php
        while( $q->have_posts() ): $q->the_post();
        ?><li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></li><?php
        endwhile;
        ?></ul><?php
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else:
        _e( 'Sorry no posts found!' );
    endif;       
endif;
```

---

## Alternativa

Esta alternativa pode ou não resultar, tudo depende do que pretendes fazer.

Assumindo que pretendes ordenar por prioridade de 9 a 0 e depois ficar com ordenação alfabética de A a Z dentro de cada prioridade podes:

```
// ...
'orderby' => array(
    'wpcf-prioridade-parceiro' => 'DESC', // 1º de 9 a 0 na prioridade
    'title'                    => 'ASC'   // Depois de A a Z no título
)
// ...
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Só precisei customizar a maneira de como era mostrado o resultado, pois os parceiros mostrados com prioridade diferente de 0 precisam ficar em destaque usando uma utilizando classe CSS diferente dos demais.

Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Parabéns pela eficiência e pela paciência em ajudar. Creio que será útil para muita gente, pois não achei nenhum artigo sobre isso.

Um abraço!